# Hibernate Envers - Audited Entity can't recover ID from empty audited table relation

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I need some help on Hibernate Envers. I have the following scenario:

I have a Entity in Hibernate/JPA and this Entity has a normal configuration:

```
    package com.algar.fsw.siscos.model;

/**
 * TbUsuario generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCCTB023_USUARIO")
@Audited
@AuditTable("SCCTB047_USUARIO_ADTRA")
public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NU_USUARIO", nullable = false, scale = 0)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NO_USUARIO", nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 50)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "NO_LOGIN", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 16)
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 16)
    private String login;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NU_PERFIL", nullable = false)
    private Perfil perfil = new Perfil();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usuario" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UsuarioGrupo> usuariosGrupos = new ArrayList<UsuarioGrupo>();

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(Long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Perfil getPerfil() {
        return perfil;
    }
    public void setPerfil(Perfil perfil) {
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }

    public List<UsuarioGrupo> getUsuariosGrupos() {
        return usuariosGrupos;
    }
    public void setUsuariosGrupos(List<UsuarioGrupo> usuariosGrupos) {
        this.usuariosGrupos = usuariosGrupos;
    }
}
```

And, this Entity has a relation with this Entity:

```
package com.algar.fsw.siscos.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SCCTB018_PERFIL")
@Audited
@AuditTable("SCCTB042_PERFIL_ADTRA")
public class Perfil implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NU_PERFIL", nullable = false, scale = 0)
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NO_PERFIL", nullable = false, length = 30)
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PerfilEnum perfilEnum;

    @Column(name = "IC_ATIVO", nullable = false, precision = 1, scale = 0)
    private boolean ativo = true;

    @Column(name = "NU_NIVEL", nullable = false, precision = 1, scale = 0)
    private Long nivel;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return perfilEnum.toString();
    }

    public boolean isAtivo() {
        return ativo;
    }
    public void setAtivo(boolean ativo) {
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }

    public Long getNivel() {
        return nivel;
    }

    public void setNivel(Long nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

    public PerfilEnum getPerfilEnum() {
        return perfilEnum;
    }

    public void setPerfilEnum(PerfilEnum perfilEnum) {
        this.perfilEnum = perfilEnum;
    }
}
```

When I retrieve the Usuario information, everything is ok, but when I call the method **getPerfil** I receive a NoEntityFoundException because of the ID of the relation. The data exists only in the regular table, in the audited table the data does not exist because the Audited tables were created after the data already exists in the original table so no records were putted on audited table . I need to recover only the ID, I don't need the data from Perfil. So, if I call **getPerfil**, the only thing I need is the ID information.

Does anyone know a workaround or some solution for this kind of problem?

The reason I need this is because of an WEB application that has a screen that shows the changes in some Entity, showing the values: date_created, property_changed, value_before and value_after. So I'm constructing the logic to compare the revisions manually in java.

Please, could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a native sql query on the table and pull the id. You'll want to pull the revision id initially (to make the query), and then re-request the data (to get the requisite id using a native query).

Answer (score -1):

If you had data before starting to use Envers, you should create an initial "0" revision containing all that data.

Comment: i have the same problem, do you know of a way to generate the '0' revision?

Comment: Just copy all the data from the existing tables into a '0' revision.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue and the only solution (workaround) that helped me was to manual insert all data prior to envers as initial revision 1 with zero timestamp (1970-01-01). For your case it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO REVINFO(REV, REVTSTMP) VALUES(1, 0);

INSERT INTO SCCTB047_USUARIO_ADTRA
(REV, REVTYPE, NU_USUARIO, NO_USUARIO, NO_LOGIN, NU_PERFIL)
SELECT 1, 0, NU_USUARIO, NO_USUARIO, NO_LOGIN, NU_PERFIL FROM SCCTB023_USUARIO;

INSERT INTO SCCTB042_PERFIL_ADTRA
(REV, REVTYPE, NU_PERFIL, NO_PERFIL, IC_ATIVO, NU_NIVEL)
SELECT 1, 0, NU_PERFIL, NO_PERFIL, IC_ATIVO, NU_NIVEL FROM SCCTB018_PERFIL;
```